# Custom Markers Google Maps Street View Xcode for text overlay

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-street-view

Is there is a way to do custom markers in Google Maps Street View (GMSPanoramaView) in Xcode? I can find tutorials for doing custom markers in regular mapView but cannot find a way to do custom markers in street view. Is this possible?

I need to overlay text at specific locations, and there is (as far as I know) no way of displaying the snippet automatically in street view, so I was going to have a custom marker where the marker icon would be an image of the text label. Are there any other ways to get the text overlay at location effect? I am working with Maps SDK for iOS and Xcode (Swift).

If you are able to offer any insight, I would really appreciate this!! Thank you so much. (By the way, I am a relatively new at coding, so please be specific in advice!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, if you want to use *Street View in Maps SDK for iOS*, you must read the Google Maps Platform [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview) regarding the service to learn more.

Here is a sample snippet of the code where I create a marker to the StreetView Panorama:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

 override func loadView() {
    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: .zero)
    self.view = panoView

    panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.858, longitude: 2.294))
    panoView.camera = GMSPanoramaCamera(heading: 200, pitch: -10, zoom: 1)

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.858, longitude: 2.294)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

    // Add the marker to a GMSPanoramaView object named panoView
    marker.panoramaView = panoView
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker_image")
 }
}
```

You can notice the line `marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker_image")`, this is where you put the name of the image that you want as your marker. In my case I made a **New Image Set** in my *Assets* and put the image I want to use as my custom marker.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I really appreciate it :)